# How to get null if expression return type is void?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to compile expression with void return type to delegate with object return type. I would like to get null value in that case.

```
var inputArg0 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "arg0");
var inputArg1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(CancellationToken), "arg1");
var inputArg0Converted = Expression.Convert(inputArg0, inputArg0Type);
var instanceExpression = Expression.Constant(instance);
var call = Expression.Call(instanceExpression, methodInfo, inputArg0Converted, inputArg1);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, CancellationToken, object>>(call, inputArg0, inputArg1);
var _delegate = lambda.Compile();

// works
public string Ping(object e, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return "OK";
}

// can't compile this MethodInfo to Func<object, CancellationToken, object>
public void Update(ObjectChangedEvent e, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Please give some more details about what exactly you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your action method inside of a Func that returns null, like this:

```
Func<object, CancellationToken, object> l = (object e, CancellationToken d ) =>
{
    Update((ObjectChangedEvent) e, d);
    return null;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Action`s instead of `Func`s for void return types, try this:

```
Action<object, CancellationToken, object>
```